# SilverSprite runs as White Page

Tags: c#, silverlight, xna, silverlight-5.0

I've been attempting to bring some of my XNA games to the web with Silversprite. However, whenever I run these apps they appear as a white screen.

I am wondering if anyone has any idea on how this might be fixed.

I have followed the tutorials exactly (except replacing the XNA apps they used with my own). Nothing is working.

Has anyone figured a way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ExEn instead of Silversprite.

http://exen.codeplex.com

ExEn is a high-performance implementation of a subset of the XNA API that runs on Silverlight, iOS and Android.

It's production ready.

Here are some samples:

- My samples (if you want, I can upload you the source code):

  - Pacman: http://vackup.blogspot.com.ar/2011/09/xna-3-pacman-ported-to-silverlight.html
  - Pong: http://www.mylittlebets.com/Pong/TestPage.html
- From ExEn creator:

  - http://andrewrussell.net/2011/02/exen-home-stretch-y-arms/
  - http://andrewrussell.net/lightblocks/

Comment: Hey, I checked it out and the library does work significantly better than SilverSprite, however, I'm still getting a blank page.

Could the problem be that I do not use the default component's of XNA. Instead I use my own objects.

Comment: Open browser's JavaScript console to see errors (i use it on chrome). The most common mistake is related to content files. Read exen checklist (inside documentation). Good luck!